# Raspberry PI Zero W only as webpage viewer

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I am biulding a 3D printer and the display is managed by a raspberry pi zero W. The only porpouse of the raspberry is to load the control webpage of "Duet Web control". In my case the address is 192.168.0.36. I did that installing Raspberry pi OS (32 bit) with DE. When the boot process ends, a script executes that starts Midori (a web browser), goes to fullscreen and loads the webpage. the problem is that the pi zero W is so underpowered that the webpage never loads.

- 0.00 : Power on
- 1:14 : Cursor appears
- 1:50 : Desktop fully loaded
- 1:51 : Midori starts loading webpage
- 3:57 : midori only shows a white screen with no loading bar

Is there any OS designed only to view a webpage?
can i uninstall the DE bout maintain the browser in a gui version?